# Default Programs Bar Gray-out

Tags: 13.04, window

I've had this problem since I upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and have been trying to fix it ever since, but I have tried everything I could think of.  My problem happens with most of the default programs (LibreOffice, Firefox, Software Center, etc.) and with one downloaded program called MuseScore.  What happens is when I click the top bar (Where minimize, maximize, close are) the windows goes to the backgound and doesn't do what I clicked on.  This is especially frustrating when another window is behind it, because then that window closes.  I am currently using the Cairo Dock session, but the problem ocurs on the Gnome Fallback as well (the default Ubuntu session has been dead since upgrade and is at a point of no return).  Any help would be appreciated!  I will post screenshots (or a video if possible) upon request.

Here are my hardware details:

- Lenovo IdeaPad N580.
- Pentium 4 B960 @ 2.2GHz; upgraded 8GB RAM.
- Intel HD Graphics integrated with CPU.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that might happen if you don't have graphics drivers properly installed. If you see anything on the list with the Additional drivers program, make sure it is properly configured and running.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it is not a driver problem.  All the drivers are in the kernel and it seems to be more of a software issue

Comment: Mmk, make sure they *are* in the kernel - sometimes it lies and they have to be reinstalled. You might want to include whether or not you have a special type of mouse.

Comment: No, just the touchpad on the laptop.  How do I check if it's a driver issue if nothing has ever come up?

Comment: You can do one of three things: Check to see if the driver is listed in Additional Drivers as "Installed but not in use", check the output of `lsmod` or see the System Monitor to see if the module is listed, and check the Xorg logs.

Comment: It seems to be in lsmod and there is no addition drivers list in the settings.  By the way, it's not a dedicated graphics card, it's integrated into the CPU.

Comment: That's very weird... there are no additional drivers listed, yet the module name of one is listed in `lsmod`? Are you sure? What hardware do you have and what module was listed?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I meant it wasn't listed in the command output

Comment: Ok, what kind of computer do you have? Can you list the make and model or else provide details?

Comment: Lenovo IdeaPad N580.  Pentium 4 B960 @ 2.2GHz, upgraded 8GB RAM. Intel HD Graphics integrated with CPU

Comment: Not sure how to go about diagnosing the Cairo Dock problem... but perhaps if you started a new question about the default Ubuntu session not working that would be more easily fixable at this point.